# iOS views not drawing aggressively enough (require force of frame change)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

In my app that I've been working on for about 6 months now, I've seen a very weird bug in a few places relating to drawing of views. I've built 20+ ios apps, and this is the only project where I've seen anything like this. I must say it has me scratching my head.

Basically a couple of views do not draw until the frame changes, or for a tableview I have, until I scroll it off screen. These views tend to be outside the bounds of their superview that is eventually resized to reveal them (though not always). When the superview is resized the subview is not redrawn.

This happens even with just a simple `UITextView` in a nib. However, the text view shows up as soon as I scroll the superview which is a `UIScrollView` (causing a redraw). The bounds/frames are correct and I've checked all views are not hidden and their alpha is 1.0

Is this expected behaviour? Calling `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsLayout` does nothing as this just marks the view as needing to be redrawn.

I put together this absolutely terrible hack to force the drawing, and fortunately I only need to use it in about 2 minor places, but I would really love to know what is going on.

This is probably overkill, but I can't waste anymore time on a bug I believe exists in `UIView` or `CALayer`.

```
//Don't use this unless a view really really really really won't draw when it should
- (void)twForceDraw
{
  CGAffineTransform transform = self.transform;
  CGRect frame  = self.frame;
  CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
  self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  self.frame = CGRectZero;
  self.bounds = CGRectZero;
  self.frame = frame;
  self.bounds = bounds;
  self.transform = transform;
  [self setNeedsLayout];
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Any thoughts what might be causing this?

Comment: Are the view frames being changed or drawn in a background thread, by any chance? In that case the change of the parent view frame would trigger a redraw on the main thread and cause them to appear.

Comment: Nope. All UI is handled on the main thread. Just double checked a known occurrence of the issue and all frame changes for the view are on the main thread